# My React Ionic pages are loading twice, how can i fixe that?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, mobile, capacitor

My google maps pages is loading twice. I suspected the IonReactRouter in view of the various answers on the forums that I could find. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G3Kw.png). It's disabling but it seems to generalize on all my other pages. Do you have any ideas where it could come from?
I'm using Ionic with react, with capacitor/googleMaps plugin for the maps. I can show you my Tab4 page with my map if your asking, my App.tsx code : setupIonicReact();

```
const App: React.FC = () => (
<IonApp>
  <IonReactRouter>
    <Menu />
    <IonTabs>
      <IonRouterOutlet id='main'>
        <Route path="/" exact={true}>
          <Redirect to="/pages/Welcome/Welcome" />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/pages/Contact/Contact" component={Contact} strict={true} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/pages/FAQ/FAQ" component={FAQ} strict={true} exact={true} />
        <Route path='/pages/AboutUs/AboutUs' component={AboutUs} strict={true} exact={true} />
        <Route path='/pages/AccountPage/AccountPage' component={AccountPage} strict={true} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/pages/welcome" component={WelcomePage} />

        <Route exact path="/tab1" component={Tab1}>
          <Tab1 />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/tab2" exact={true} component={Tab2}>
          <Tab2 />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/tab4" component={Tab4}>
          <Tab4 />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" exact={true}>
          <Redirect to="/tab1" />
        </Route>
      </IonRouterOutlet>
      <IonTabBar className='ion-tab-bar' slot="bottom">
        <IonTabButton tab="tab1" href="/tab1">
          <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={home} />
          <IonLabel>Home</IonLabel>
        </IonTabButton>
        <IonTabButton tab="tab2" href="/tab2">
          <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={speedometer} />
          <IonLabel>Compteurs</IonLabel>
        </IonTabButton>
        <IonTabButton tab="tab4" href="/tab4">
          <IonIcon aria-hidden="true" icon={navigateOutline} />
          <IonLabel>Trouver ma borne</IonLabel>
        </IonTabButton>
      </IonTabBar>
    </IonTabs>
  </IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>


);

export default App;
```

I tried placing console.logs to see if it was only the map that was loading twice or the page. And that turns out to be the page.
When I edit my page to reload it, the create map only happens once. And the console messages appear.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAIMV.png)

Comment: do you use React's strict mode?

Comment: I'm using strict mode, just took it off. And my problem disappeared. I feel a bit silly. What is it used for ? Thank you for the quick reply !

Comment: Yes, that's perfect.